# How do I make sure my Dropdown Icon never leaves its position as I scroll down my web page?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to stop my dropdown Icon from scrolling as I scroll to the bottom of the webpage. I used JavaScript to add a new class to the .List as soon as the Icon is clicked. It acts as it should up until it clicked and even with a position absolute it still leaves the top right the very moment I begin to scroll.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    ul.List li a.nav-link {
        list-style: none;
        display: none;
    }

  ul.List li a.nav-link {
    display: none;
    
  }
  ul.List li.dropdown-icon {
 top: 10px;
 right: 20px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
/*    padding-top: 12px;*/
    height: auto;
    min-height: 33px;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 0.9em;
      
}
 ul.List.responsive li {
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    }
ul.List.responsive li.dropdown-icon {
     position:absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 20px;
    }
ul.List.responsive {
   flex-direction: column;

  }
   

 ul.List.responsive li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
   list-style: none;
     

 }
    
    

   

}
```

```html
<nav class="Top-Nav  container ">
    <div class="brandName"><span id="cap">c</span>rib<span id="frm-style">Farm</span></div>
    <ul class="List" id="dropDownclick">
     <li class="show-responsive"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>Home</a></li>
     <li class="show-responsive"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Gallery</a></li>
     <li class="show-responsive"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Our goal</a></li>
     <li class="show-responsive"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Who we are</a></li>
     <li class="show-responsive"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact us</a></li>
     <li class="dropdown-icon" id="d-icon"><a onclick="dropDownMenu()" href="#" >&#9776</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
```

Comment: Try `position: fixed`

Comment: I tried that already before I posted the question, It didn't work. @douglas

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you don't want the icon to move when the page is scrolled you'd have to make it `position:fixed` *but* then its' positioned in relation to the *viewport* not the menu. You may have to rethink here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this once -

```
.Top-Nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand your question. I just found two errors here `&#9776;` is the actual Unicode. And you have to define `dropDownMenu()` in your inline js/internal js/external js file.

Comment: I did,
 function dropDownMenu() {
        var x = document.getElementById("dropDownclick");
        if( x.className === "List") {
           x.className += " responsive";
        } else {
            x.className = "List";
        }
    }